# I have been contacted by somebody saying their name is Pauline one of Facebook's employees saying I have won $500,000

Tags: facebook

I was contacted on a Sunday by some woman calling yourself Pauline saying she works for Facebook and that I have won a $500,000 promotion by Facebook

Comment: yeah, you won it - buy us beer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not give away money. This is a scam, usually they will ask that you to pay a fee or place a deposit in order to claim the prize. A [similar case is documented on the ACCC Sacm Watch website](https://www.scamwatch.gov.au/get-help/real-life-stories/unexpected-prize-lottery-scam-davins-fictional-facebook-lottery-win).

You should [report the message](https://www.facebook.com/help/217854714899185?helpref=faq_content) to Facebook. Also see [this Facebook help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/1674717642789671) on avoiding scams.